# How to display watermark only on fullscreen image Product Page Magento 2.3.4

Tags: product-images, catalog, magento2.3.4, watermark

> Actually i set Watermark for base image from backend **Content => Design
>   => Configuration => Product Image Watermarks** tab
>
> In my requirement: Only Watermark should display on product fullscreen
>   image once we click on  product page images once it will be in
>   fullscreen then it will display but not on product page normal images.
>
> If we set watermark base image from magento backend it is displaying
>   on products normal images and fullscreen view also. Actually i want
>   to remove the watermark on products base images on product page but it
>   should have to display in fullscreen view.

[image]

> If anyone having an idea please guide me, Thanks in Advance !!!.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this? Can you please post the answer if you achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to set this for each size like base, thumbnail, small and swatch images.

See:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-image-watermarks.html

Don't forget to clear Product-Image-Cache in backend system->cache->
"Flush Catalog Images Cache Pregenerated product images files"

Comment: watermark is working fine but i am trying customize it. please read the question.

Comment: @hitesh, Have you got the solution for this? Can you please post the answer if you achieved this?